# How to make floating LIs equally share their parent ULs width?

Tags: css, width, html-lists, stretch

A note ahead: I did look for answers before asking but none of which i found accurately explained how to do this right.

I have some DIVs, somewhere within i have an UL which is supposed to stretch to a 100% of the parent DIV, and within the UL i have a (varying, due to dynamic content) amount of LI-elements which i would like to equally share the space the parent UL provides to them (which obviously should be 100%).

I tried various solutions, such as inline-block on the LIs, as well as float:left and automatic width on the LIs

I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EfWze/) here.

How can i achieve the desired result (with no use of JS) and at least major cross-browser compatibility?

Comment: Sounds like an ideal use for [Flexbox](http://benfrain.com/understanding-the-css3-flexbox-flexible-box-layout-module/) - but sadly, that really is in no way cross-browser yet!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `display: table;` with `width: 100%;` on the UL and `display: table-cell;` on the LIs:

```
ul {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
li {
    display: table-cell;
    background: #eee;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/EfWze/1/

Comment: Wow, this looks promising! I applied it to my actual coding situation but for some reason the LIs are not double their former height. I try figuring it out.

Comment: I figured it out - i had dynamic "richtext content" in the buttons and it was containing multiple <p></p> groups, which then caused paragraphs and thus line wrapping within the button. Problem solved. THANK YOU!

Comment: Just as an info.. (even if you wouldn't care about it):
display: table-cell is only supported from IE versions 8+

Comment: But with 2% of the world using Ie7, what does it matter? http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

Comment: Sure, compatibility is an issue and i'd prefer it if it works well in IE7 as well. But this is the best solution so far.

Comment: I completely understand, that's what I also would do. Wanted to mention it (you know..for my webdeveloper-"duty") :)